# How to sort column using ORDER BY RIGHT()

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to sort a column using ORDER BY in SQL in MS ACCESS where the values have different digits places as in the photo shown. Here's some sample data

[image]

For example, when I use

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(Conn_D, LEN(Conn_D) - 1), Pin_D ASC
```

it doesn't recognize when there's P101 when there's P20 - it'll recognize P101 as "10" instead of "101" and recognizes P20 as "20"

How can I get it to recognize P101 as "101" while recognizing P20 as "20?"

Comment: 20, as a string, sorts *after* 100 (dictionary order). Convert the value to integers for correct sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mid` for this:

```sql
ORDER BY VAL(MID(Conn_D, 2)) ASC, Pin_D
```

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is the same, you can sort them by length and then by value:

```
order by len(conn_d) desc, conn_d desc
```

Comment: This is smart, but unfortunately the prefixes aren't the same. They'll be represented in "J" and "P"

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer, I needed to use VAL() after taking out the digits so

```
VAL(ORDER BY RIGHT(Conn_D, LEN(Conn_D) - 1) ASC, Pin_D ASC)
```